# regex for telephone number in validation form

Tags: django, regex, bootstrap-5

in a django template with the html pattern tag and boostrap for form validation

with this regex it validates a sequence of numbers that can be separated by a dash

```
"^[+-]?\d(?:-?\d)+$"
```

example:

```
12-65-25-75-84 or 12-255-0214
```

the javascript :

```
(() => {
    'use strict'    
    const forms = document.querySelectorAll('.needs-validation')
    
    Array.from(forms).forEach(form => {
        form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
            if (!form.checkValidity()) {
                event.preventDefault()
                event.stopPropagation()
            }

            form.classList.add('was-validated')
        }, false)
    })
})()
```

and the html

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1" name="tel" id="tel" placeholder="Tel" pattern="^[+-]?\d(?:-?\d)+$" required>
                            </div>
```

I would like to know how to modify it to have the possibility of putting spaces between the numbers (in addition to the dashes)

example:

12 57 125-98-457

and limit the total number of digits to 15 (excluding spaces and dashes)

for example a string like this:

```
12-28-35-74-12
```

or

```
12 28 35 74 12
```

or
123-478 25 12 124-15

thank you

Comment: Maybe `"^\d(?:[ -]?\d){14}$"`?

Comment: this `^([\d -]*[0-9])$` should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use:

```
^[0-9](?:[ -]?[0-9]){0,14}$
```

[See RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/RzhoGe/1)

1. `^` - Matches the start of the string.
2. `[0-9]` - Matches a single digit (0, 1, ... 9).
3. `(?:` - Start of a non-capturing group.
4. `[ -]?` - Optionally matches either a space or '-'.
5. `[0-9]` - Matches a single digit (0, 1, ... 9).
6. `)` - End of the non-capturing group.
7. `{0,14}` - Maches the previous token, i.e. the previous non-capturing group, from 0 to 14 times.
8. `$` - Matches the end of the string.

Comment: Thank you very much Booboo for all these explanations.